# SCSS Interfaces in Typescript 4.0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, typescript4.0

I'm trying to expose SCSS color values to my React app through Typescript by defining them via an `interface`. Here's a sandbox that used to work well under Typescript v3: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-night-92rij

It stopped working when upgrading to CRA and Typescript 4. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your stylesheet isn't being parsed/imported as a css module so `colors.primary` is resolving to `undefined`.

[CRA's naming convention for css modules is `[name].module.scss`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/).

This works if you just rename your files with this naming convention so your css modules get passed through the correct loader behind the scenes as seen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-margulis-q6nle?file=/src/app/theme/index.ts

```js
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import colors from "./colors.module.scss";

export const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: colors.background
    },
    primary: {
      main: colors.primary
    }
  }
});
```

TLDR: Rename your files:

```
colors.scss      -> colors.module.scss
colors.scss.d.ts -> colors.module.scss.d.ts
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this right away! Any idea why it was working with CRA 3.0?

Comment: No clue, it looks like it was added in `2.0.3` https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/commit/fc7c9915b0dee9d2777322bf9c433006730d3839 my guess would be `@material-ui/core/styles` version changed to add that validation because that error is not a TS error, it's thrown by `@material-ui/core`